# What is access token that flutter_auth is asking for facebook login?

Tags: facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter

I am trying to

```
_auth.signInWithFacebook(accessToken: null);
```

There is no documentation on what is accessToken. 
Where do I get this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the accessToken from facebook itself.

There is a package [flutter_facebook_login](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_facebook_login) that interfaces with facebook to get that accessToken

```
var facebookLogin = new FacebookLogin();
var result = await facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(['email']);
var accessToken = result.accessToken;
await _auth.signInWithFacebook(accessToken: accessToken.token);
```

However with Facebook you do need to register the app with them to connect. Instructions are within the [flutter_facebook_login](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_facebook_login) package ReadMe.